# Clearing rows of floating blocks with different heights

Tags: html, css

I'm using a slightly modified Soh Tanaka's [Smart Columns](http://web.archive.org/web/20110309231700/http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/smart-columns-w-css-jquery/), but in his example all blocks/columns have the same height. If I have divs with different heights, the technique breaks like in the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LCDDD/show/). I don't like how DeSandro's [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/basic-single-column.html) handles the height problem because it rescrambles the blocks depending on window size so the list loses its implied sequential ordering, so I'm exploring a different solution.

The solution I'm currently trying is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/LCDDD/show/), but I have problem trying to clear the sides of the rows/lines. I can use javascript to insert a `<span style="clear: both;"></span>` to the ends of every rows/lines, but this causes more problems when the window is resized and if there is multiple groups of such smart columns in a single page. While I'm sure I can write a script to deal with those cases, I think there might be an easier way.

What is the easiest way to make it such that when a list of floating blocks needs to wrap, it should start at the bottom of the tallest box on the previous row/line? A CSS-only solution is preferred, but a javascript/jQuery-based solution would be acceptable.

Rephrased in another way, I want to float blocks like how letters of different sizes are "floated" (letters are vertically aligned at their baseline by default, though for div blocks a top alignment would probably looks better):

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could switch from `float: left` to `display: inline-block; vertical-align: top`.

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/LCDDD/1/

I also added a tiny bit of JavaScript:

```
$(this.config.column_selector).contents().filter(function() { return this.nodeType === 3; }).remove();
```

`inline-block` is unfortunately affected by whitespace in the HTML, so that snippet removes text nodes between the `li` elements. Alternatively, there are CSS fixes available (with downsides), or you could just [remove the whitespace in your HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/LCDDD/2/).

Comment: Instead of the JS, just set `font-size: 0` to the parent of the `inline-block` elements. This removes whitespace. You can then set font-size back to a regular value for the text inside the `inline-block` elements.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this what you're looking for, but I guess I had a similar problem a while back. To my help, I've written this little plugin (though the name is a bit unfitting for it's function):

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.extend({
    fixLineBreak: function(css) {
      var minLeft = $(this).position().left;
      return $(this).each(function() {
        var position = $(this).position();
        if (position.left > minLeft && $(this).prev().position().left >= position.left) {
          $(this).css(css);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}(jQuery));
```

You would use it like so:

```
$('#my_boxwrapper li').fixLineBreak({
  clear: 'left'
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/v79Cu/

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by thirtydot, inline-block is definitely the way to go. You can certainly achieve this with just css.

On your wrapper (I think you named it "column"), give it the following css:

```
.col-group {
  font-family: monospace; /* for spacing columns correctly */
  letter-spacing: -.65em; /* this too */
  margin-left: -1em; 
  margin-right: -1em;
  text-align: left; /* center or justify for columns in last row */
  display: block;
}
```

Then on your columns (I think you named these "box"), apply this css:

```
.box {
  font-family: Serif; /* be sure to reset the font and letter-spacing */
  letter-spacing: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  position: relative;
  float: none;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top; /* align row's columns along top or baseline */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I haven't used Smart Columns, but it seems like it could work quite well in tandem with this css as it's only changing widths, right?

Anyways, you can check out a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/9U6v5/25/show/) or play around with it in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9U6v5/25/). I call this the "Inline-Block Grid" and I wrote a [blog post](http://paulcpederson.com/articles/inline-block-grid/) about it as well.

Comment: This is the way to do it.  Removed my complex JavaScript implementation, and works beautifully.  Thanks!